# Set cache key by calling an external C code in nginx configuration

Tags: c, nginx, lua

This may be better servered on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), however, I'm evaluating nginx to determine if it's able to solve a particular problem.

#### Problem

I want to use nginx response caching with FastCGI Cache. But I need to set the cache key with a value from a cookie. The problem is the cookie needs to be decrypted before I can get the value to use it in the cache key.

#### What I Know

I know how to configure nginx as a cache ([`fastcgi_cache`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_cache)). I also know I can set and use a custom variables in the cache key (`fastcgi_cache_key`). However, I don't know how to call a custom function to decrypt the cookie. I know nginx has the concept of modules. I have also noticed integration with Lua.

#### Question

Provided my decryption is available as C code, can I access this external code from the nginx configuration and use its return value?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your code is in C, easiest solution would be to write simple nginx module which provides a variable with the decrypted value.  Relatively simple example of how to provide a variable may be found in [ngx_http_secure_link_module](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/trunk/src/http/modules/ngx_http_secure_link_module.c).

Comment: I also found an example module, [`set_misc_*`](https://github.com/agentzh/set-misc-nginx-module), I will likely reverse engineer. Given the bounty, I was hoping for a more thorough answer. However, I'm marking this as the answer since the reference you provided is *more* to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Lua module can indeed help you if compiled it with LuaJIT.

Look here for a simple example of how to interact with cookies: http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2011-January/024798.html

Now with LuaJIT you could use the FFI to call your C decryption code: http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html

Another possibility would be to do it all in C, which may be faster but would probably be more work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Given the bounty, I was hoping for a more thorough answer. Nonetheless, I will review the links you provided.